# appending files into multiple files depending on the appended files line count in unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I have a scenario where i have lot of file in folder and i need to all files in such a format that appended files threshold is 5000,  if its more than that it should create a new file...and for the new file also threshold should be 5000. have tried the below logic which works only for the first appended file.

```
ls -ltr *re.txt | awk '{print $9}' > files.txt 

 touch file_int.txt
 touch file_count.txt
 for file in `cat files.txt`
do
    cat file_count.txt >> file_int.txt
    count=`wc -l < file_int.txt`
    count1=`wc -l < $file`
    count3=`expr $count + $count1`
    file_date_time=file_`date +%H_%M_%S_%N`.txt
    if [ $count3 -gt 5000 ]
        then
        cat $file >> $file_date_time
        cat $file_date_time > file_int.txt  
    else
        cat $file >> file_count.txt
    fi
done
```

Comment: rephrase your question, whatever you have typed seems confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to consider using the split command:

```
split -l 5000 bigfile.txt `date +%H_%M_%S`
```

The filenames might not be exactly what you need, but split will break up your file into 5000 line chunks.

You could rewrite your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir to_delete
for file in *re.txt
do
   split -l 5000 $file ${file}_`date +%H_%M_%S_`
   mv $file to_delete/.
done
```

If it works ok you can then delete the contents of the `to_delete` directory.